# How to compare two form fields in html forms in ektron?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ektron

I am working on ektron 9.I have created an html form in ektron.Suppose i have two fields in that email and confirm email .I need to compare these two fields on submitting the form.How can i achieve it by using **custom validation**?

I had tried it by giving **Data Type** as **Plain Text** and Condition as **../ConfirmEmail != ../Email**. But seems not working,everytime it shows the message what i have given , even when both fields are equal.

Any idea on this?

Comment: You might want to consider following up on some of your earlier questions on SO by accepting answers.

Comment: This question has already been asked on another site and has had further discussion. Linking here for reference. https://developer.ektron.com/Forums/?v=t&t=2576